# Reference to another file function

Tags: javascript, function

I have 2 .js files: list.js and filter.js. The list.js have a reference to filter.js.

```
  //filter.js
    function isAnother(){
    ...
    }

    //list.js

   /// <reference path="~/Scripts/filter.js"/>
   var report= function loadList(){
       ...
       var self=this;
       self.loadItem = function(id)
       isAnother();**//Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**
       ...
    }
```

I get an error **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function** in isAnother() call. I realise that in debug panel in Google Chrome there is no filter.js file loaded in Scripts folder. How can I reference to this function properly?

Comment: Assuming you are in an HTML page, first include filter.js, then include list.js using one <script src=""> HTML tag for each .js file

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing these two files in a web browser make sure you have linked both JavaScript files in the HTML page.

```
<script src="filter.js"></script>
<script src="list.js"></script>
```